# Can Facebook Graph API edit facebook event?

Tags: facebook

I have tried to create facebook event by graph api:

```
FB.api('/123/events', 'POST', {
      name: 'Moon',
      start_time: '2012-11-05T00:00:00+0700',
      end_time: '2012-11-16T00:00:00+0700',
      location: 'My country',
      description: 'Mooncake',
      privacy_type: 'OPEN'
}, function (res) {
    console.info('create event: ', res);
});
```

"123" is my facebook id.

The event is created successfully with response event id = "456"

I tried to update it:

```
FB.api('/456', 'POST', {
    name: 'HoneyMoon'

}, function (res) {
    console.info('edit event: ', res);
});
```

But, I can not update it, this is facebook response:

```
Object { message="(#200) Permissions error", type="OAuthException", code=200}
```

I'm sure that I am admin that event.

Can you help me answer this question?

Thank you very much

Comment: Are you using page token or your user token?

Comment: Yes, I am. I have created and updated the event in facebook app

Answer (score 0):

Oh yeah, I found the problem.

Please enable "Events Timezone" migrations in Apps > Settings > Advanced.